# Arrow Unsigned S3 Requests

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I'm hoping to read a multi-file dataset from a [public s3 bucket](https://registry.opendata.aws/speedtest-global-performance/) using the R package. Is it possible to *not* sign requests for objects like these? In the AWS CLI, that's done with the `--no-sign-request` argument. Is there any way that this can be done?

```r
library(arrow)

open_dataset(
  sources = "s3://ookla-open-data/parquet/performance/",
  partitioning = c("type", "year", "quarter"),
  hive_style = TRUE,
  format = "parquet"
)
#> Error: IOError: When getting information for key 'parquet/performance' in bucket 'ookla-open-data': AWS Error [code 100]: No response body.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about specifying `sources = s3_bucket("ookla-open-data/parquet/performance", anonymous = TRUE)`?

`s3_bucket()` accepts that and other configuration options for the S3 connection; see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/FileSystem.html for a full list. Some of those options can be encoded in the S3 URI, but not all.